# Show bind mounts as a separate filesystem

Tags: bind-mount

I'm designing something that uses a lot of bind mounts. However, bind mounts show up as the same type as the host filesystem. This is bad as backup programs (like rsync) will read all the bind mounts. I could use a FUSE option like `bindfs`, but FUSE has a lot of idiosyncrasies (reading `/proc/self` and `/dev` fail). So, is it possible to bind mount but show them as separate filesystems?

I could use NFS, though that seems far more work than it's worth --- I need to set up `/etc/exports`, etc., just to access things on the same computer.

Comment: Or you can present for backup a separate bind mount (again) that would not include any of the offending bind mounts you created so the backup tool won't backup duplicates. Doesn't address the question but does address the problem.

Comment: OTOH it's useful (and likely important) that `[ /orig/file -ef /bind/file ]` return true if that's the same file or that `lsof /orig/file` returns the processes that open the file via its `/bind/file` path. It sounds to me you would be better of configuring your backup program to work around the problem using A.B's approach or some use of `--exclude*`

Comment: Or ... you can enumerate the *source filesystems* you want to back up (not the directory heirarchies, which may contain multiple mounts/bind mounts), and back up each filesystem as a unit. Ignore the bind mounts, and backup only the *real* filesystems.  If your /etc/fstab gets backed up also, then it will already know how to put those filesystems back to their bind-mounted locations. This sounds like a classic use case for `rsync -x ...` (or better, ZFS).